# HTML Element in jaspersoft studio pro

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am using the HTML Element of jaspersoft studio, and pass an image with an static path plus a text from data base to it. My report page layout is two column layout. I am facing these problems with that:

- The html element does not stretch to the text content and it cuts the text. Beside it gets repeated to the other column as well, which I am no sure if is because of the stretching issue.
- I can see the result only as HTML. As PDF the text is **very small** and all of it is on **one line**! There is no line break.

The HTML Element:

```
"<style>.ImageLeft { float: left; width :40%;}</style> <img class = ImageLeft src= 'C:/Users/iman.gharib/JaspersoftWorkspace/Qualitätsreport/LBLogos/aort.png' /> <p>"+$F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Einleitungstext} +"</p>"
```

HTML output:
 [image: html]

PDF output:
[image: pdf]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could LaTeX be an alternative or is this a document with dynamic reports for other users? Seems like some kind of a thesis to me.

Comment: No, it is for other users. It is a report which has to interact with database and has to be exported at least in PDF.